# CSS Height 100% doesn't work when overflowed

Tags: javascript, html, css

What's happening is that with this code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="one">

    <div class="will-overflow">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.one {
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}

.one .will-overflow {
    width: 20%;
    height: 2000px;
    background: blue;
}
```

I get a result like this:
[image]

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/kM46e/

**Question**

Is there anyway to expand the div.one height to fit the **div.will-overflow**. This is just an example, the content of that div is dynamic.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?

Comment: I showed as 120%, because I want to make an example of what happens if that div goes over the body height.

Comment: If you're asking why the height of red is as is, I'd gather that - `height: 100%` on red makes it the same height as its container. Now - `height: 120%` on blue makes its height 120% of its container. Red won't scale to the height of its child element, as it would have to be `auto`: http://jsfiddle.net/kM46e/2/, and you've defined it already. If you were to set it to `auto` then the blue wouldn't be able to stretch it, as 120% of 0 is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.one {
    min-height: 100%;
    background: red;
}

.one .will-overflow {
    width: 20%;
    height: 1000px;
    background: blue;
}
```

By changing `.one`'s `height` into `min-height`, you make it stretchy. However, now `height: 100%` of `.will-overflow` doesn't work, since without anything to stretch it, `.one` will have height of 0; so I change the `height` to `1000px` to simulate some arbitrary-length content. Change it to a small value like `10px` to check that it will still allow `.one` to fill the entire viewport.

Comment: Thanks, I am happy there is still someone in this world that reads the full post.

Answer (score 0):

Height correct is 100%.

```
.one .will-overflow {
    width: 20%;
    height: 120%;
    background: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kM46e/1/

Comment: I showed as 120%, because I want to make an example of what happens if that div overflows the body height.